# Python strange int behavior

Tags: python, int

Take a look at this:

```
print 41063625 ** (1.0/3)  # cube-root(41063625) = 345
print int(345.0)
print int(41063625 ** (1.0/3))
```

It outputs:

```
345.0
345
344
```

I was expecting the last line to be `345`, since I was expecting `int(41063625 ** (1.0/3))` to equal `int(345.0)` to in turn equal `345`, as the other two outputs suggest. However, this is evidently not the case. Can anyone give me any insight as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Print (or rather `float.__str__`) is rounding the output.

```
In [22]: str( 41063625 ** (1.0/3) )
Out[22]: '345.0'
```

The floating point representation for 
`41063625 ** (1.0/3)` is less than 345, so when you take the `int` of it, you get 344 rather than 345.

```
In [15]: 41063625 ** (1.0/3)
Out[15]: 344.9999999999999

In [16]: int(345.0)
Out[16]: 345

In [17]: int(41063625 ** (1.0/3))
Out[17]: 344
```

If you want the closest int, you could use round:

```
In [18]: round(41063625 ** (1.0/3))
Out[18]: 345.0
```

or, to get an `int`:

```
In [19]: int(round(41063625 ** (1.0/3)))
Out[19]: 345
```

Comment: Ah alright that makes sense - didn't know it was a feature of `print` to round like that. Thanks!

Comment: It might be illustrative to post the output of `str( 41063625 ** (1.0/3) )` since that is what `print` actually prints.

Comment: @A.R.S.: In 3.2+ `float.__str__` uses the `repr`, which uses the minimum number of digits to round back to the original float. For example: `print(41063625 ** (1.0/3))` outputs `344.9999999999999`.

Answer (score 1):

because `41063625 ** (1.0/3)` is not 345.0:

```
In [7]: 41063625 ** (1.0/3)
Out[7]: 344.9999999999999

In [8]: int(344.9999999999999)
Out[8]: 344
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I got from the calculations is something like this:

```
>>> 41063625 ** (1.0/3)
344.9999999999999
>>> int(345.0)
345
>>> int(41063625 ** (1.0/3))
344
```

So getting 344 is absolutely right. The internal representation of floating point numbers lacks some accuracy, so casting to `int` will always give the floor value.

You can use the [`round()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function to get a more reasonable value.